# Capacitors minimum value

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, component-values

When the manufacturer recommends some capacitors with specific values, can I choose caps with more capacitance? Will it give any advantage? For example decoupling caps at MCU power pins. Or LDO input and output caps.

Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily. Read the datasheet closely.

Comment: If you're putting in a screw, can you pick any screw-driver you like, or are there ones that fit perfectly, ones that work okay, ones that sort of work and ones that are absolutely the wrong choice?

Comment: I am reading it very closely. For example, STM32f405 datasheet suggest 1uF and 10nF caps, but in examples across the Internet I see working examples with 100nF or even 2.2uF caps. So, is there a rule, or maybe a limit?

Comment: There are certain accepted values, but you would need to do a complete AC analysis to determine the appropriate range of values.

Comment: @RomanSimonyan the reason you are likely to see those specific values is because they're very commonly used as decoupling capacitors for a lot of ICs. It's not necessarily right, but sometimes it doesn't matter. You have to read the data sheet to know and, even then, sometimes experience will still tell you to use certain values. Total board capacitance is also a factor sometimes. This is a deceivingly hard topic to master. It's best to try to stick with the data sheet for each part, though.

Comment: "working examples" on Internet do not necessarily mean that they have good ripple rejection or good transient response (no ringing, overshoots or undershoots) to abrupt load jumps, as it frequently happens with MCUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has two parts: caps on LDO, and decoupling caps on MCU. Because these functional blocks are physically separated on a PCB and linked via wires (or planes), there is some degree of de-coupling, and frequently there is an intentional de-coupling in a form of ferrite beads and inductors. So the question of cap selection can be treated separately, in first approximation.

For LDO, is is advisable to use manufacturer's specifications. Always. Each LDO is designed to meet certain specific needs. Some LDO are designed to be "[capless](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/34551/tradeoffs-of-ldo-architectures-and-the-advantages-of-advanced-architecture-capless-ldos.html)", to better suite portable devices with explicit power gating. Less caps allow for faster power-on time and less waste on power-off. These LDO will be unstable (or make overshoots) with bigger load caps. Some older LDOs need certain range of ESR in the load cap. Thus some excellent MLCC with a milliohm-ESR will make it unstable, so some lesser-quality aluminum or tantalum cap is needed to fix this. Or you would need to add an explicit 1-Ohm resistor in series with ceramic cap. Some even older LDOs require hundreds of uF to be stable.

For the MCU, bigger capacitors are likely not good. The purpose of these caps is to mitigate short spikes of current that a (badly designed) MCU can demand during intricacies of their running software, which can run in 10-100-1000MHz range. Bigger caps (like 1uF) are effectively inductors at frequencies above 10MHz, and will fail to do the job. To better accommodate the entire spectrum of power spikes, a network of caps is frequently used, say 100nF, 5nF, 220pF in parallel.

In any case it will save you a lot of time and troubles if you follow manufacturer's suggested layout and bypass network topology and follow the suggested BOM, without much of "choosing".

Answer (score 3):

**Usually** when an LDO circuit recommends a minimum value of a decoupling capacitor to ground, a larger one will do.

However, an LDO is a surprisingly difficult thing to design well, and maintain stability, into whatever the unknown customer is going to throw at it. The designers might have assumed requirements on the circuit that are not obvious.

The now well-known 'ceramic versus tantalum ESR' issues with LDOs are a case in point. A larger tantalum capacitor will usually have a lower ESR than a smaller one, and so breach the minimum ESR requirements, even if the capacitance is OK. Older LDOs required a nominal ESR, but newer ones can work with ESR right down to zero, the data sheet will tell you which.

Always read the data sheet carefully to understand whether component values are nominals, minimums or maximums. It's the only way the designer of the component has for talking to you, to get you to provide the electrical environment that he has designed the part to work in.

Just because you see a circuit working OK on youtube does not mean that's a good way to use it, there may be other features of that particular circuit that aren't apparent to you as a viewer. The original IC designer will have tested his circuit over extremes of temperature and process variation, the one you see working may be an unusual example.